# ASP.NET access file behind browser authentication prompt

Tags: asp.net, browser, authentication

I want to programmatically access a test XML feed on a 3rd party site which is behind a login, see an example below:

[image]

How can I pass the credentials to this site? Would I fill out this form programmatically? Is there a certain setup for the request url in which I can pass credentials? 
I googled but all I get is examples on authentication within an ASP.NET application.
I'd appreciate an example.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try this out yet, but this might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-with-jquery-and-ajax?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a `NetworkCredential` containing the username and password to the WebClient you're using to fetch your data.

I've provided an example using `WebClient` below.

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("YourUsername", "YourPassword");
    string data = webClient.DownloadString("YourURL");
}
```